# Categorise the datetime in to a new column based on the range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I have a dataset called `df` that looks like this:

| provider | fid | pid | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHE-223 | 2bfc9a62 | 2f43d557 | 2021-09-26T23:18:00 |
| CHE-223 | fff669e9 | 295b82e2 | 2021-08-13T09:10:00 |

I wanted to create a new table called `wave` that has categorical values for a range of date from `datetime`. e.g. For the date from 16th of November 2019 until 28th of February 2020, it gives a value before covid and so on.

I used a loop function to achieve this and this is the code I used:

```
def wave(row):
    if (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2019-11-16")) & (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-02-28")):
        wave="before covid"
    elif (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2020-03-01")) & (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-06-15")):
        wave="1st wave"
    elif (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2020-06-16"))  & (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-09-30")):
        wave="between waves"
    elif (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2020-10-01")) & (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2021-01-15")):
        wave="2nd wave"

df["wave"]=df.apply(lambda row:wave(row),axis=1)
```

But it gives me a **column** named `wave` but with no values. How do I fix this and categorise the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to return something. Also your dates comparisons are inverted:

```
(row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2019-11-16")) & (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-02-28"))
```

would match dates that are **before** the 16th of November 2019 and **at the same time after** the 28th of February 2020... which of course never happens.

Your function should look like:

```
def wave(row):
    wave = ""
    if (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2019-11-16")) and (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2020-02-28")):
        wave="before covid"
    elif (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-03-01")) and (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2020-06-15")):
        wave="1st wave"
    elif (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-06-16"))  and (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2020-09-30")):
        wave="between waves"
    elif (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2020-10-01")) and (row["datetime"] <= pd.Timestamp("2021-01-15")):
        wave="2nd wave"
    elif (row["datetime"] >= pd.Timestamp("2021-01-16")):
        wave="after second wave"
    return wave
```

Edit: also `&` is a bit-wise operator. For logical expressions use `and`.

Comment: Thank you soo much. That works perfectly except I don't think the "=" sign works. As the date such as "2020-02-28" , "2020-06-15" , those that  are mentioned in the code have an empty value in the "wave" table. Do you have any idea why that could be?